# C# vertically oriented DataGrid: change column names

Tags: c#, datagrid, dataset, dataview

I'm currently using a technique I found while poking around the interwebs for flipping a DataGrid's orientation in C# for a SharePoint web part. It's working correctly, pulling data from a SQL Server 2005 database and displaying it in the DataGrid. I'd like to know if there is a simple way to change the column names, either using an extended property in the db, or, alternately, if I can manually set them (although I have lots of columns, so I'd prefer to add an extended property to the db and display those in place of the field names).

```
// Create a new data adapter and fill a dataset with the above SQL data.
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
da.SelectCommand = cmd;
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds, "Bobst Specs");
// Flip the dataset to vertical orientation.
DataSet flipped_ds = FlipDataSet(ds);
DataView dv = flipped_ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
// Bind the dataset to a datagrid and display.
DataGrid outputGrid = new DataGrid();
outputGrid.DataSource = dv;
outputGrid.DataBind();
outputGrid.ShowHeader = false; // Remove the integer headings.
outputGrid.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
Controls.Add(outputGrid);
```

Here is the FlipDataSet method:

```
public DataSet FlipDataSet(DataSet my_DataSet) 
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    foreach (DataTable dt in my_DataSet.Tables)
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        for (int i = 0; i <= dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            table.Columns.Add(Convert.ToString(i));
        }
        DataRow r = null;
        for (int k = 0; k < dt.Columns.Count; k++)
        {
            r = table.NewRow();
            r[0] = dt.Columns[k].ToString();
            for (int j = 1; j <= dt.Rows.Count; j++)     
                r[j] = dt.Rows[j - 1][k];
            table.Rows.Add(r);
        }
        ds.Tables.Add(table);
    }
    return ds;
}
```

I'm also wondering if this is the "right" way to handle flipping the datagrid's orientation, or at the very least if there is a better way to do it in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to rename the columns by altering my SQL SELECT statement so that each field is named there. For instance:

> SELECT fldCustomerName AS [Customer
>   Name]

This works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to rename column in a data grid is

```
mygrid.Columns["EmpID"].HeaderText = "Employee ID";
```