# How to change data orientation of a dataset from vertical to horizontal in c#/.net 3.5

Tags: c#, dataset

I have a requirement where I need to change the data orientation of a datatable. Suppose I have the data spread vertically:

```
Year    |  0-20  |  21-40  |  41-60  |  >61   |  Total 
% total |  11.5  |  26.5   |  42.0   |  20.0  |  100.0

I want a method to change the orientation to horizontal like:
Year   |  % Total
0-20   |  11.5
21-40  |  26.5
41-60  |  42.0
>61    |  20.0
Total  |  100.0
```

I am using C# with .net 3.5. I really can't change the original dataset. I have to do something in my code to handle it. This converted dataset will be fed to an existing function to do further processing. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: thanks campbell and norman, both the solution doesn't add the correct column header name. The headers are getting included as part of data. I will try to tweak the code to make it usable.

Answer (score 1):

[Taken from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2312422/c-vertically-oriented-datagrid-change-column-names)

```
public DataSet FlipDataSet(DataSet my_DataSet) 
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        foreach (DataTable dt in my_DataSet.Tables)
        {
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            for (int i = 0; i <= dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                table.Columns.Add(Convert.ToString(i));
            }
            DataRow r = null;
            for (int k = 0; k < dt.Columns.Count; k++)
            {
                r = table.NewRow();
                r[0] = dt.Columns[k].ToString();
                for (int j = 1; j <= dt.Rows.Count; j++)     
                    r[j] = dt.Rows[j - 1][k];
                table.Rows.Add(r);
            }
            ds.Tables.Add(table);
        }
        return ds;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to pivot a DataTable.

Here's a method that'll help take each of your columns and turn them into rows. It's up to you to make the finer details work as per your requirements.

```
private DataTable PivotTable(DataTable origTable)
{

    DataTable newTable = new DataTable();
    DataRow dr = null;

    //Add Columns to new Table
    for (int i = 0; i <= origTable.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        newTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(origTable.Columns[i].ColumnName, typeof(String)));
    }

    //Execute the Pivot Method
    for (int cols = 0; cols < origTable.Columns.Count; cols++)
    {
        dr = newTable.NewRow();
        for (int rows = 0; rows < origTable.Rows.Count; rows++)
        {
            if (rows < origTable.Columns.Count)
            {
                dr[0] = origTable.Columns[cols].ColumnName; // Add the Column Name in the first Column
                dr[rows + 1] = origTable.Rows[rows][cols];
            }
        }
        newTable.Rows.Add(dr); //add the DataRow to the new Table rows collection
    }
    return newTable;
}
```